# Create different margin setting for section 2 (dynamically)

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-word-2010, templates

I have a Word template that has for starting only 1 page and that page has specific margins and header/footer pictures. The problem is that if the user fills the 1st page and jumps to the 2nd page or adds a page break/section break the same margins and header/footer are applied. Is there a solution where I can add a default margin and header/footer picture after 1st page?

Answer (score 0):

*Respectfully, I disagree with the previous response, even though it answered the question as asked. That suggested a Section break, which is the only way to change *margins.* The problem is that in Word, the user does not really want to change the margin.*

**There are standard, tried and true, methods for creating letterhead where the first page looks and acts as if there are different margins, without a section break.**

- [Setting Up Letter Templates](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/LetterheadRibbon.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill
- [How Can I Have a Different Header/Footer on the Second Page?](http://addbalance.com/word/headersfooters.htm#2007-2013) (my page)
- [Basic Letterhead Template](http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#BasicLetterheadTemplate) (my page)

The basic idea to simulate different margins within the same section is to insert a borderless TextBox or Frame with wrapping in either the first-page header or the first-page footer. This structure acts like a temporary margin, pushing text in the body out of the way.

The actual page margin settings are the same throughout, but they appear to be different on the first page. That is, the margins are set for both pages at the settings for the second and following pages.

Done this way, the user simply types on the first page as with any Word document. When text flows onto the second page it will act as if there are different margins even though there are not. This method works for all four sides of the paper, independently.

If you have a section break, the user must be cognizant of that section break and type around it.

You may also want to look at my writing on [Margins and Indents](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/basic_formatting.htm#Margins_and_Indents).

Answer (score -1):

Add a new section and page to the template and apply the required setting to that section. Your template will now have two pages, the second page will be empty but with all the correct settings.

Step by step instructions *for Word 2010*:

1. Under the `Page Layout` menu click the `Breaks` drop-down menu and select `Next Page` (below  the `Section Breaks` grey title). A new section and a new page are added.
2. Under the `Page Layout` menu click the `Margins` drop-down menu and apply your desired settings.
3. Initially the header and footer will be the same as the first section so click the `Link to Previous` button under the `Design` menu (this menu is displayed only when editing the header or footer).
4. Save the template.

Comment: See my posted answer.